# How to send many requests in minimal time with Python 3

Tags: python, httprequest, python-asyncio

My task is to send 30-100 post requests to one url in one exact precise moment of time. For example in 13:00:00.550 with several milliseconds accuracy.
Requests are differ from each other (some types, for example 10 types). And each type must send 5 times.
I have problem with fast sending of http requests. Is there the fastest way to send 30-100 post requests in minimal time?
I tried to use asyncio and httpx.AsyncClient to do it.
Here the part of code how I made it:

```
from datetime import datetime
import asyncio
import httpx

async def async_post(request_data):
    time_to_sleep = 0.005
    action_time = '13:00:00'
    time_microseconds = 550000

    async with httpx.AsyncClient(cookies=request_data['cookies']) as client:

        while True:
            now_time_second = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            if action_time==now_time_second:
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(0.05)

        while True:
            now_time_microsecond = datetime.now().strftime('%f')
            if now_time_microsecond >= time_microseconds:
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(0.003)

        for _ in range(5):
            response = await client.post(request_data['url'],
                                         headers = request_data['headers'],
                                         params = request_data['params'],
                                         data = request_data['data'],
                                         timeout = 60)

            logger.info('Time: ' + str(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')))
            logger.info('Text: ' + str(response.text))
            logger.info('Response time: ' + str(response.headers['Date']))

            await asyncio.sleep(time_to_sleep)


def main():

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(
        asyncio.gather(*[async_post(request_data) for request_data in all_requests_data]))
```

all_requests_data - list of all types of requests.

request_data - dict that contains data of request

As result - the time between requests can reach 70-200 ms. That's a lot. It does not suit for me.
And it's not server lag. I tried other application, and could see, that server can make answers in few miliseconds. So that is not on server side.
How to send requests faster?

Comment: if you're doing performance test, try mature tools such as **jmeter**

Comment: No. It's not a perfomance test. I have to catch some fast changes on server. And I know Python only :)

Comment: If the URL is on a remote host, you will have to deal with network latency, which can vary in ways from bothering to dreadful. Also, have you considered how time is relative ? That is not a metaphysical question, but hitting the URL at the precise time on their and is difficult in itself. Also, for such level of performance, I would choose another language, lower level to relax at least one side of the eaquation. And you should look at your OS's interfaces documentation, there may be ways to lower lantencies. I consider this a difficult task, good luck !

Comment: Hitting the URL at precise time on known network - is not a big problem. I can to find out it by several experiments.  
But the main problem is a series of requests with small lags between them.

Comment: @jor77 "Hitting the URL at precise time on known network" > precise time in milliseconds?